# Perl delete similar strings in an array

Tags: arrays, string, perl

I am new to Perl programming.

I need to find and delete *partially* matching strings in an array.

For example in my array there are strings:

```
@array = qw(abcd.txt abcdeff.txt abcdweff.txt abcdefrgt.txt);
```

I just want the first **abcd.txt** to be saved to the array and to delete the rest (which are similar in the first 4 characters) i.e. so that it will print only **abcd.txt** when `@print "@array";` is called.

Comment: This is not a duplicate, it differs somewhat.

Comment: `@print "@array";` is wrong. It should be `print "@array";`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
my %seen;
@array = grep !$seen{ substr($_,0,4) }++, @array;
```

Comment: Thank you it works
How about this 
@array = qw (abcd.txt abcdeff.txt abcdweff.txt abcdefrgt.txt efghijk.txt efghijksdf.txt efghijkasdfw.txt);

Comment: what about that?  it should work for that too, getting rid of any elements that have the same first four characters as a previous element

Comment: Yea, it works as well.